# Is it possible to log a message from an Oozie Workflow without killing it

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I've got a somewhat complex Oozie work flow and I'd like to be able to see some of the properties at various points in the flow. The obvious solution is to simply write a message to the logs.

I've gone through the [official documentation](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html), and it appears that the only action that supports logging is the Kill action!

Is there anyway to log a set of properties without killing the workflow?

**Update** (to provide more details)

So imagine my (simplified) workflow looks something like:

```
<workflow-app name="myWorkflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
  <start to="action1"/>

  <kill name="Kill">
    <message>Failed: error ${myField}</message>
  </kill>

  <action name='action1'>
    <java>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
           <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>default</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <main-class>my.Class</main-class>
        <arg>${myArgument}</arg>
        <capture-output/>
    </java>
    <ok to="action2" />
    <error to="Kill" />
  </action>

  <action name='action2'>
    <ok to="End" />
    <error to="Kill" />
  </action>

  <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Inside the workflow I've got fields called ${myField}, ${myArgument}, ${jobTracker} and ${nameNode}. Some of these are properties set by the launching process others will be set by the Java class I call from 'action1'. 
In-between executing 'action1' and 'action2' I'd like log the values of these fields. I don't much care where the values are logged to, I just need to be able to see what the values are.

I do NOT want to call my 'kill' action to do the logging because it's important that 'action2' is run.

Comment: Did you mean `message` element in the `kill` node? What kind of logs are you talking about and what properties you want to print?

Comment: @ YoungHobbit, I've added some more details to the question that should explain the problem in more details. The short answer is that I want to log any variable that can be used as an Oozie expression. I don't care what logs I write to, just something I can read later.

Comment: `${myField}, ${myArgument}, ${jobTracker} and ${nameNode}` all of these will be defined in the `job.properties` file. what do you mean by `others will be set by the Java class I call from 'action1'.` Do you want to write some properties during one action and later want to use them  in the following actions for that their is different mechanism. I am sure what you need here.

Comment: sort of, but... 1) I've got more than one job.properties file, 2) My Java task has some 'magic' (actually it's reading a database) to retrieve data and using it up update a couple of properties. These will be used later in the workflow.

Comment: Oozie accepts only one properties file while submitting the job. You need to write these extra properties which are calculated in the java action and used in the downwards actions. You can use the `System.getProperty("oozie.action.output.properties")` file and write your `key=value` pairs into it. Further you can access these by `${wf:actionData('java_action_name')['key']}`. The maximum data you can write is 2KB.

Comment: That's fine - at different times I want to run the same workflow with a slightly different configuration, hence the use of different properties file. Also, the 2Kb limit isn't an issue

Comment: If you want to run with different configuration, then you need to re-submit them with the respective configuration file.

Comment: That's exactly what I do. I'd still like to be able to log the values though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I could see is you can put a shell script at the end of your workflow with the values to be logged as parameters to the shell script. Inside the shell script write the values of those parameters in a file and copy the file to hdfs.

Once the job is done you can check the value of those properties in the file stored in hdfs.

Hope this helps.